# intersect and any or contains and any. Which is more efficient to find at least one common element?

Tags: c#, linq

If I have two list and I want to know if there are at least one common element, I have this two options:

```
lst1.Intersect(lst2).Any();

Lst1.Any(x => lst2.Contains(x));
```

The two options give me the result that I expect, however I don't know what is the best option. Which is more efficient? And why?

Thanks.

EDIT: when I created this post, apart of the solution, I was looking the reason. I know that I can run tests, but I wouldn't know the reason of the result. One is faster than the other? Is always one solution best than the other?

So for this reason, I hace accepted the answer of Matthew, not only for the test code, but also he explain when one is better than other and why.  I appreciate a lot the contributions of Nicholas and Oren too.

Thanks.

Comment: Run some tests, or look at the IL generated?

Comment: From http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/ _If you have two horses and you want to know which of the two is the faster then **race your horses**._

Comment: If one is performing markedly better or worse than the other, then the question of `Why?` would be valid.  But without knowing anything about your data, it's impossible to answer.

Comment: Use a `Stopwatch` and time them. Then compare the two.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Oren's answer has an error in the way the stopwatch is being used. It isn't being reset at the end of the loop after the time taken by `Any()` has been measured.

Note how it goes back to the start of the loop with the stopwatch never being `Reset()` so that the time that is added to `intersect` *includes* the time taken by `Any()`.

Following is a corrected version.

A release build run outside any debugger gives this result on my PC:

```
Intersect:    1ms
Any:       6743ms
```

Note how I'm making two non-overlapping string lists for this test. Also note that this is a worst-case test.

Where there are many intersections (or intersections that happen to occur near the start of the data) then Oren is quite correct to say that `Any()` should be faster.

If the real data usually contains intersections then it's likely that it is better to use `Any()`. Otherwise, use `Intersect()`. It's very data dependent.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        void run()
        {
            double intersect = 0;
            double any = 0;

            Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();

            List<string> L1 = Enumerable.Range(0, 10000).Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList();
            List<string> L2 = Enumerable.Range(10000, 10000).Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                stopWatch.Restart();
                Intersect(L1, L2);
                stopWatch.Stop();
                intersect += stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

                stopWatch.Restart();
                Any(L1, L2);
                stopWatch.Stop();
                any += stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Intersect: " + intersect + "ms");
            Console.WriteLine("Any: " + any + "ms");
        }

        private static bool Any(List<string> lst1, List<string> lst2)
        {
            return lst1.Any(lst2.Contains);
        }

        private static bool Intersect(List<string> lst1, List<string> lst2)
        {
            return lst1.Intersect(lst2).Any();
        }            

        static void Main()
        {
            new Program().run();
        }
    }
}
```

For comparative purposes, I wrote my own test comparing `int` sequences:

```
intersect took 00:00:00.0065928
any took       00:00:08.6706195
```

The code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        void run()
        {
            var lst1 = Enumerable.Range(0, 10000);
            var lst2 = Enumerable.Range(10000, 10000);

            int count = 10;

            DemoUtil.Time(() => lst1.Intersect(lst2).Any(), "intersect", count);
            DemoUtil.Time(() => lst1.Any(lst2.Contains),     "any",      count);
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            new Program().run();
        }
    }

    static class DemoUtil
    {
        public static void Print(this object self)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(self);
        }

        public static void Print(this string self)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(self);
        }

        public static void Print<T>(this IEnumerable<T> self)
        {
            foreach (var item in self)
                Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

        public static void Time(Action action, string title, int count)
        {
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
                action();

            (title + " took " + sw.Elapsed).Print();
        }
    }
}
```

If I also time this for *overlapping* ranges by changing the lists to this and upping the `count` to 10000:

```
var lst1 = Enumerable.Range(10000, 10000);
var lst2 = Enumerable.Range(10000, 10000);
```

I get these results:

```
intersect took 00:00:03.2607476
any took 00:00:00.0019170
```

In this case `Any()` is clearly much faster.

**Conclusion**

The worst-case performance is very bad for `Any()` but acceptible for `Intersect()`.
The best-case performance is extremely good for `Any()` and bad for `Intersect()`.
(and best-case for `Any()` is probably worst-case for `Intersect()`!)

The `Any()` approach is O(N^2) in the worst case and O(1) in the best case.
The `Intersect()` approach is always O(N) (since it uses hashing, not sorting, otherwise it would be O(N(Log(N))).

You must also consider the memory usage: the `Intersect()` method needs to take a copy of one of the inputs, whereas `Any()` doesn't.

Therefore to make the best decision you really need to know the characteristics of the real data, and actually perform tests.

If you really don't want the `Any()` to turn into an O(N^2) in the worst case, then you should use `Intersect()`. However, the chances are that you will be best off using `Any()`.

**And of course, most of the time none of this matters!**

Unless you've discovered this part of the code to be a bottleneck, this is of merely academic interest. You shouldn't waste your time with this kind of analysis if there's no problem. :)

Comment: Note that the input data has a significant impact on performance here.  Certain types of data will result in one being faster while different data will result in the other being faster.  It's a matter of determining which is more likely to be the case given the situations the OP will be in.

Comment: @Servy Indeed, I was deliberately testing worst-case performance where there is no intersection.

Comment: A good answer to this question would describe what types of situations would result in best/worst performance for each algorithm, as well as how it scales for values in-between those cases.  Then the reader can determine where their data is most likely to fit, and use the appropriate algorithm.  Here `Any`/`Contains` has the fastest best case, but the slowest worst case, and will generally be slower than `Intersect` with a wide variety of input, so `Intersect` is probably best unless you know a lot about the likely data inputs.

Comment: They key issue here is that if the first first item in the source sequence is in the second sequence `Contains` is quicker.  If the second or third item is there then it also might end up being quicker.  Unless it's one of just the first few though, `Intersect` will be quicker.  `Intersect` has a larger memory footprint though; all of the items in the second sequence need to be copied to a `HashSet`, the `Contains` version doesn't need to do that.

Comment: fast or slow, `Any` to me is much more readable. If its a tough call, I will stick to it. +1 for the excellent analysis.

Comment: As someone said up in the question's comments: [See Eric Lippert's rant](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/): `Unfortunately, implementing code that ensures an upper bound on your worst-possible-scenario behaviour often ends up making the typical-case-scenario unacceptably slower, and vice versa.`

Comment: @Bobson Yes indeed, there are definitely trade-offs, as I point out in my conclusion.

Comment: There's also `Enumerable.Any(lst1.Intersect(lst2))`, which some may find is more readable than `lst1.Intersect(lst2).Any()`, but gives the same performance benefits (and drawbacks). Very good analysis of the alternatives, @MatthewWatson

Comment: @JimMischel The second code snippet you provided is literally translated into the former by the compiler.  The IL will be *identical*, so obviously the performance traits will be the same.

Comment: @Servy: I thought that's what I said. Suppose I could have been more explicit.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the implementation of your IEnumerables.

Your first try (`Intersect`/`Any`), finds all the matches and then determines if the set is empty or not. From the documentation, this looks to be something like O(n) operation:

> When the object returned by this method is enumerated, Intersect enumerates first,
>   collecting all distinct elements of that sequence. It then enumerates [the]
>   second, marking those elements that occur in both sequences. Finally, the marked
>   elements are yielded in the order in which they were collected.

Your second try ( `Any`/`Contains` ) enumerates over the first collection, an O(n) operation, and for each item in the first collection, enumerates over the second, another O(n) operation, to see if a matching element is found. This makes it something like an O(n<sup>2</sup>) operation, does it not? Which do you think might be faster?

One thing to consider, though, is that the `Contains()` lookup for certain collection or set types (e.g., dictionaries, binary trees or ordered collections that allow a binary search or hashtable lookup) might be a cheap operation if the `Contains()` implementation is smart enough to take advantage of the semantics of the collection upon which it is operating.

But you'll need to experiment with *your* collection types to find out which works better.

Answer (score 1):

See Matthew's answer for a complete and accurate breakdown.

Relatively easy to mock up and try yourself:

```
        bool found;

        double intersect = 0;
        double any = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            List<string> L1 = GenerateNumberStrings(200000);
            List<string> L2 = GenerateNumberStrings(60000);
            Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();

            stopWatch.Start();
            found = Intersect(L1, L2);
            stopWatch.Stop();
            intersect += stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

            stopWatch.Reset();

            stopWatch.Start();
            found = Any(L1, L2);
            stopWatch.Stop();
            any += stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Intersect: " + intersect + "ms");
        Console.WriteLine("Any: " + any + "ms");
    }

    private static bool Any(List<string> lst1, List<string> lst2)
    {
        return lst1.Any(x => lst2.Contains(x));
    }

    private static bool Intersect(List<string> lst1, List<string> lst2)
    {
        return lst1.Intersect(lst2).Any();
    }
```

You'll find that the `Any` method is significantly faster in the long run, likely because it does not require the memory allocations and setup that intersect requires (`Any` stops and returns `true` as soon as it finds a match whereas `Intersect` actually needs to store the matches in a new `List<T>`).

Comment: GenerateNumberStrings is a method from .NET or is a implemented method?

Comment: @Oren I do agree that `Any()` is probably the best choice, but there's an error in your test code which needs to be fixed before the results will be meaningful.

Comment: Good catch, thanks for the heads up, updated for correctness and referred to your answer.