# checking if an item with a valid conditiona actually exist in an foreachloop

Tags: c#, .net, json, loops, serialization

I have two Json files . One file (jOne) Specifies to check for the availability of something (some key and value) in the other JSON file (jTwo)

jOne  :- Which specifies what are the required values that need to be looked up in the second JSON file

```
[
{
"IdInOne": "001",
"NameInOne": "Name_2"
},
{
"IdInOne": "002",
"NameInOne": "Name_3"
}
]
```

jTwo :- File Which is Supposed to have the values specifed in JOne

```
[
{
"IdInTwo": "001",
"NameInTwo": "Name_1"
},
{
"IdInTwo": "001",
"NameInTwo": "Name_2"
},
{
"IdInTwo": "001",
"NameInTwo": "Name_3"
},
{
"IdInTwo": "002",
"NameInTwo": "Name_4"
}
]
```

So what I am trying to do is check if a certain specified json key and value pair actually exist in a given separate JSON , so in the Specified example in my first JSON file the value IdInOne": "001",NameInOne": "Name_2" and I want to check if the 2nd JSON file actually has a key and value that matches EXACTLY . In the second JSON There are multiple matches where the IdInOne (001) is equal to the IdInTwo but only a single value has both the ID and Name which matches to a specified one.

I Simply want to validate this and print a message if the match is successful and print a separate value if the match is unsuccesful

Here is the Code that I have tried and I am finding it hard to check if a value actually exists

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string jOne = @"D:\DelTemp\test.json";
        string jTwo = @"D:\DelTemp\test2.json";

        string jOneContent = File.ReadAllText(jOne);
        string jTwoContent = File.ReadAllText(jTwo);

        var InfoInOne = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<One>>(jOneContent);

        var InfoInTwo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Two>>(jTwoContent);


        foreach (var itemInOne in InfoInOne)
        {
            foreach (var itemInTwo in InfoInTwo.Where(n => n.IdInTwo == itemInOne.IdInOne && n.NameInTwo==itemInOne.NameInOne))
            {
                if (itemInTwo.exists())
                {
                   //sucess message must be printed
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Item not found" + itemInTwo.NameInTwo)
                }


            }
        }
    }
}

public class One
{
    public string IdInOne { get; set; }
    public string NameInOne { get; set; }
}

public class Two
{
    public string IdInTwo { get; set; }
    public string NameInTwo { get; set; }
}
```

Note :- A downside of my current implementation is bad performance I beileive so is there any better way to implement this . Also only want to print the Error message saying that required/specified object is not found after it has fully iterated and confirmed that it is not there in the second JSON file

Would Really appreciate any help on this

Edit :- The  Interesct method does not work as I get the error `Two' does not contain a definition for 'exists' and no accessible extension method 'exists' accepting a first argument of type 'Two'`

Comment: are you looking for `InfoInTwo.Any(n => n.IdInTwo == itemInOne.IdInOne && n.NameInTwo==itemInOne.NameInOne)`, which returns a `bool` suitable for an `if` test?

Comment: @MarcGravell that would be a pretty good solution too .. any idea how to implement it ?
Also just want to check is there any alternate implementation to what I have done ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [intersect and any or contains and any. Which is more efficient to find at least one common element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17153688/intersect-and-any-or-contains-and-any-which-is-more-efficient-to-find-at-least)

Comment: Hi @aloisdgmovingtocodidact.com it does not . I get the Error " It does not contain definition ...."
Can you please revert the strike ?

Comment: `exists` should be `Exists()` and be sure that you are using Linq and that you have rebuild your project.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Enumerable.Except`. For example,

```
var dataNotInInfoTwo = InfoInOne.Select(x=>new {ID=x.IdInOne,Name=x.NameInOne})
               .Except(InfoInTwo.Select(x=>new {ID=x.IdInTwo,Name=x.NameInTwo}));

foreach(var item in dataNotInInfoTwo)
{
        Console.WriteLine($"Data Not Found : ID : {item.ID}, Name:{item.Name}");
}
```

Output

```
Data Not Found : ID : 002, Name:Name_3
```

Comment: I think thats a great way to check whats not there but I also want to Print a message to confirm that it is there ?
Anyway Ican do  it here ?

Answer (score 0):

This is untested for your circumstance but I imagine will work...
Not sure if you want to compare all or any, so here is both:

```
// Will tell you if all the elements in InfoInOne are also found in InfoInTwo
if (InfoInOne.All(x => InfoInTwo.Contains(x)))
{

}
// Will give you a list of all the items found to be in both lists
var matches = InfoInOne.FindAll(x => InfoInTwo.Contains(x));
```

EDIT I missed the part where you want separate output for success and no success so for that you can use this:

```
foreach (var result in InfoInOne)
{
    if(InfoInTwo.Contains(result)) //sucess message must be printed
    else Console.WriteLine("Item not found" + result.NameInOne) // This in NameInOne, not NameInTwo
}
```

There should be no need to pick apart the fields here as the objects only contain primitive types, and will be considered equal, or to be contained, in the other list if they match exactly.

Comment: Hi
Thanks for the reply , but what is x ? 
There are two values that I want to check for